# Launch Elastic Beanstalk app without Load Balancer using config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I launch an AWS EB application "single-instance environment"<sup>[1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html?ref_=pe_395030_31184250_9)</sup> using a config file? I'm guessing there's an option I can set in either my `config.yml` file, or in my `.config` file in `.ebextensions`, but I have been googling myself in circles trying to find what the option is called.

Comment: are you creating the application in the console? if not, how are you creating it? (for instance, eb cli, aws eb cli, cloudformation). I'm not sure it's possible aside from the console.

Comment: when issuing `eb create` a single instance env is created. what's the question then?

Comment: @Tal actually when doing `eb create` the default is to create a load-balancing, autoscaling environment, not a single-instance environment

Comment: @tedder42 it looks like it is possible without using the console by specifying an option in an `.ebextensions` config file. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the documentation on all the options available for `.ebextensions` files [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html).

Looks like adding the following to a config file in `.ebextenstions` will do the trick:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
    option_name: EnvironmentType
    value: SingleInstance
```

In the documentation you can see that the default for this option is `LoadBalanced`.

Comment: great find. I dug for a while and couldn't find it the "definitions page" you found for the var.